# Heroku Sendgrid Add-on

Tags: ruby-on-rails, api, heroku, sendgrid, add-on

Can't seem to access the admin dashboard for Sendgrid via heroku > app > config add-ons option.

So here's what I'm doing: 
Log in > Choose app > Click the add-on for sendgrid > `SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected end of data at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data`

And that's it. I can't for the life of me get past that error code and I don't know how to stop if from crashing.

Comment: Try to add it via commands? install heroku toolbelt and login, then clone the app like heroku git:clone -a myapp, then add sendgrip addone like heroku addons:create sendgrid:starter, refer to https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sendgrid

Comment: I have the same issue and I installed via CLI